# which is efficient way to make a database using mysql for faster retriving

Tags: mysql

I have to make a database which will be having 200000 rows in table1 & 10000 rows in table2,3,4,5 like that. i will be using mysql. so which approach will give me faster result.

1. Distributing data to multiple tables,
2. Keeping less number of tables with lots of rows.

What is the speed of mysql to traverse a table and to join them & traverse.

Comment: Primary key lookups using InnoDB will probably give you results instantly (in less than a second). You didn't specify criteria for retrieving records, whether you're joining tables or not while searching. However, 200k rows isn't that much, properly configured MySQL instance will give you results back fairly fast, assuming you don't do carthesian product of 200k rows with 10k rows from remaining tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your first concern about table design should be normalization and correct indexes.

If you encounter performance deficits (I doubt that with 200000 rows, thats not that much), then measure the difference with normalized and denormalized structures.

Only denormalize after you have benchmarked and confirmed that the denormalized structure is really faster. So, if your number two means normalized tables with 200 000 rows, I would go with number two.